# what is causing a segmentation error?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

can you please tell me what is causing a segmentation error in this piece of code
Note:this is a solution for a TopCoder problem.

```
class GridGenerator{
public:
int generate(vector <int> row, vector <int> col){
int i,j;
int n=col.size();
vector<vector<int>>vec;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            vec[0][i]=col[i];
            vec[i][0]=row[i];
        }
for(i=1;i<n;i++)
{
    for(j=1;j<n;j++)
        vec[i][j]=vec[i-1][j]+vec[i][j-1]+vec[i-1][j-1];
}
return vec[n-1][n-1];
}
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`vector<vector<int>>vec;` declares an empty vector, accessing elements in it is undefined behavior, as it has no elements to start off with.

Comment: OP wants to say `vector<vector<int>>vec(n, vector<int>(n));`. Can you please add it to your answer?

Comment: @AndyG I thought about it, and no. That'd be counter-productive imo. I think he'd be better off if he looked up vector initialization by himself. :)

Comment: thank you very much and sorry for taking your time :)

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Fair enough :-)